# Header in Full-Page view gets in the way of code output

Tags: bug

[image]

This is the current state of viewing a code snippet in full-page mode. Whatever is at the top of the rendered content gets covered by the site header.

I thought that the header used to disappear in full-page mode, or when the user scrolled down the page - I could be wrong.

Possible solutions to this could be:

1. Put some `padding-top` on the rendered content for every post in full-page mode.
2. Hide the header in full-page mode.